# LayoutInflater doesn't seem to be linked with id in layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater

**I am completely lost with this LayoutInflater**. I am trying to link items in code with items located in a remote layout. I have tried three different versions of the inflater creation. None of them work. However, this version seems to be the most widely used. Here is a snippet of the inflater garble:

```
setContentView(R.layout.browse);

LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final ImageButton editBrowseButton = (ImageButton) li.inflate(R.layout.row, null).findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
editBrowseButton.setAlpha(50);
```

This feels kinda like I missing something. Do I need to return something? The .setAlpha has no meaning. I just put it in to test the inlater. Obviously, it doesn't change the transparency. And if I add an onClickListner, it doesn't work. However, I don't get an exception. The activity starts up fine. Here is the relevant XML code for row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:focusable="true"
>
    <TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    >
    <TextView 
    android:id= "@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text = "Item"
    android:focusable="true"
   />  
     </TableRow> 


    <TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    >
        <ImageButton 
        android:src="@drawable/editbtn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"

        ></ImageButton>



    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT_01**

New approach tried and failed. Same results. Nothing happens.

```
setContentView(R.layout.browse);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    ViewGroup rowView = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    LinearLayout rowLinLay = (LinearLayout) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    TableRow rowTableRow = (TableRow)rowLinLay.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
    ImageButton editBrowseButton = (ImageButton) rowTableRow
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

**EDIT_02**

```
setContentView(R.layout.browse);
    ExpandableListView browseView = (ExpandableListView)     findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = (View) li.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TableRow rowTable = (TableRow) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
    ImageButton editBrowseButton = (ImageButton) rowTable
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    editBrowseButton.setAlpha(100);
```

Comment: TableRow tableRow = (TableRow ) li.inflate(
            R.layout.tableRow2, null); ImageButton editBrowseButton = (ImageButton) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

Comment: The constructor doesn't like "li.inflate(**R.layout.tableRow2**,null) tableRow2 is not a layout. The activity fails if I change that same line to "R.id.tableRow2" Also, I noticed that the top linearlayout tag was cut off above. tableRow2 tablerow rests inside of of a linearLayout. Does that matter?

Comment: If you're gonna use layoutInflator.inflate(resource, null), make sure you know about the potential side-effects: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Answer (score 0):

Now that I can see your whole question :-)

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate( R.layout.linearLayout1, null); 
 TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) linearLayout1.findViewById(R.layout.tableRow2); 
 ImageButton editBrowseButton = (ImageButton) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

Comment: Sorry about that! It will not let me pass LinearLayout1 as a layout. The name of the layout is row :(

Comment: Yeah so have you tried the id? li.inflate( R.id.linearLayout1, null);  Can you see what I'm doing. The layout should not be called Row, it should be browse ( the xml file you used with setContentView )

Comment: Yes, I have tried every possible combination. I get this Resource Exception : *Resource ID #0x7f050019 type #0x12 is not valid* when I use id in place of layout. What is really WIERD is if I use the **edit_02** format shown above, mAlpha (in the variables debug window)updates from 255 to 100. But the button's transparency doesn't change. Its almost like the change is made to the button, it just doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do. AFAIK LayoutInflater is for "creating views" from resource xml files. Well at least that's what I use it for :D.

First "A TableRow should always be used as a child of a TableLayout" - so the xml looks funny too me - simple LinearLayout would be good. (but that's not on the side)

Anyhow - problem I see with the code is that the view that you inflate is not attached (2nd paramenter is null, and than you leave it hanging).

If you want to duplicate the entry - create it n-times you should do it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.browse);

LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout row = li.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
findViewById(/*id of element you want the row to be added to*/).add(row); //now row is attached
final ImageButton editBrowseButton = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); //so this is live, visible etc
editBrowseButton.setAlpha(50); //this should work than
```