# Simple LayoutInflater not updating View

Tags: android, expandablelistview, layout-inflater

I have spent entirely too much time on this. Originally, I was using a simple "onAction" method in parallel with an XML onclick statement to control a button located inside of my ExpandableListView. I thought it would be nice to use inflation so I could have more control of the button during runtime. You can see an earlier post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541365/layoutinflater-doesnt-seem-to-be-linked-with-id-in-layout)

This is my latest attempt. I do not get any exceptions or errors, it just does nothing. I know this version is a little far fetched so if you have the time check out the link above for some of my other attempts before suggesting something I may have already tried!

**BrowseActivity.class**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.expandLinLayout);

    ExpandableListView browseView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent);

    LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    TextView rowTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);

    rowTxt.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);

.........
}
```

The **browse.xml** code that contains the list:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/expandLinLayout"
>
<ExpandableListView 
android:id = "@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/my_group_statelist"

>  
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the **row.xml** code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 


>
<TextView 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" 
android:id="@+id/txtItem" 
android:text="Item" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 


></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help or suggestions would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do, Can you tell in short, I did not get you.

Comment: I am trying to change the color of a TextView (located in a different layout) in the example above. If I can get this to work I would like to control other items in an expandableList. Things such as imageButtons, textviews,background colors etc. Basically I want to take control of views that reside in other layouts during runtime.

Comment: If you want to Inflate that layout to be as a row of `ExpandableListView` then you should use the adapter to customize your row. Have a look at subclassing [`BaseExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

Comment: I have tried using a BaseExpandableListAdapter in the past but scrapped my code because I felt like pulling information from a sql database and storing it in an array before displaying was bad. Is it ok to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to initialize layout inflater

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```